# Como criar um programa que cheque a entrada de uma variável e so prossiga ate que ela seja valida (Tipo - Valor)? Python

Tags: python, variáveis

Como criar um programa que cheque a entrada de uma variável e so prossiga ate que ela seja valida (Tipo - Valor)? Python

Nesse caso criei uma função para verificar se um valor e numero e retorna true ou false.

Gostaria de escrever uma estrutura que me permita apenas rodar a parte que calcula o saldo (as estruturas if) caso a entrada da variável saldo seja correta ou seja um valor numérico e imprima "Please enter Valid Value: ". Porem que se repita quantas vezes forem necessárias ate que a variável seja valida e possa então prosseguir para o calculo.

```
saldo = input("Please enter Saldo: ")

def isNumber(value):
    try:
        float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

while not isNumber(saldo):
    print("Please enter a valid value: ")

if isNumber(saldo):
    print("OK")

    if saldo >= 0 and saldo <= 200:
        credito = 0
    if saldo >= 201 and saldo <= 400:
        credito = 0.2 * saldo
    if saldo >= 401 and saldo <= 600:
        credito = 0.3 * saldo
    if saldo > 601:
        credito = 0.4 * saldo

else:
    print("Please Enter a Valid Value: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria diferente. Em vez de só testar se é um número, a função já poderia pedir que digite novamente, e retornar o valor somente se for válido. A solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444848/112052), apesar de funcionar, converte a string para número duas vezes (dentro da função é chamado [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) somente para verificar se é número, e depois fora da função é chamado de novo para poder fazer as comparações). Sem contar que cada mensagem é impressa duas vezes, o que dificulta a manutenção (se quiser mudar a mensagem, tem que mudar em mais de um lugar).

Enfim, a função poderia ser assim:

```
def ler_valor(mensagem, mensagem_erro):
    while True:
        try:
            valor = float(input(mensagem))
            if valor < 0:
                print(mensagem_erro)
            else:
                return valor
        except ValueError:
            print(mensagem_erro)

saldo = ler_valor('Please enter Saldo: ', 'Please enter a valid value: ')
```

`while True` cria um *loop* infinito. Ou seja, enquanto o valor digitado não for válido, eu continuo pedindo que digite novamente. Eu incluí uma verificação para quando o número for negativo, pois pelo que entendi do restante do código, o valor só pode ser positivo.

Se o valor for válido, eu retorno (o `return` sai da função, e consequentemente, interrompe o *loop* infinito).

Ou seja, se a função retornou algo, é porque com certeza o valor é válido, e eu não preciso testar novamente. Repare que na outra resposta **o `if` é redundante**, pois o código só sai do `while` quando o saldo for um número, então se saiu do *loop* é porque é um número, e portanto não precisaria testar isso novamente.

Agora esses `if`'s:

```
if saldo >= 0 and saldo <= 200:
    credito = 0
if saldo >= 201 and saldo <= 400:
    credito = 0.2 * saldo
...
```

Se o saldo for 100, ele entra no primeiro `if`. Mas logo depois ele vai testar o segundo `if`, só que isso é desnecessário, pois se ele já entrou no primeiro, com certeza não entrará no segundo, já que as condições são conflitantes (não tem como ser menor que 200 e maior que 201 ao mesmo tempo). O mesmo vale para os outros `if`'s: do jeito que está, você vai testar todas as condições desnecessariamente.

Sem contar que a última condição está errada. Se o valor for 601, não vai entrar em nenhum dos `if`'s.

Em vez disso, use `else` e `elif`:

```
if saldo <= 200:
    credito = 0
elif saldo <= 400:
    credito = 0.2 * saldo
elif saldo <= 600:
    credito = 0.3 * saldo
else:
    credito = 0.4 * saldo
```

Como a função já garantiu que o valor não é negativo, não preciso mais testar se o valor é maior que zero.

Além disso as condições foram simplificadas. Se o valor for menor ou igual a 200, ele entra no primeiro `if` e não testa as demais condições.

Se não entrar no primeiro `if`, é porque o valor é maior que 200, então eu **não preciso testar isso de novo** no `elif`. Se chegou no primeiro `elif` é porque ali naquele ponto o valor com certeza é maior que 200, então eu só preciso testar se é menor ou igual a 400.

Se não entrou no primeiro `elif`, então com certeza o valor é maior que 400 e eu não preciso testar isso de novo nos segundo `elif` (só preciso testar se é <= 600).

Por fim, no último `else`: se chegou ali é porque com certeza o valor é maior que 600 então eu não preciso testar mais nenhuma condição.

Além de evitar testes desnecessários, este código também facilita a manutenção, pois caso as faixas de valores mudem, você só precisa alterá-los uma vez (já se repetir as condições, terá que mudá-los 2 vezes).

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você só precisa adicionar uma linha no final do `while` para ler novamente a entrada do usuário. Assim:

```
while not isNumber(saldo):
    print("Please enter a valid value: ")
    saldo = input("Please enter Saldo: ")
```

E quando entrar no `if`, você terá que converter a variável `saldo` para número, já que o `input` retorna somente `strings`.

Código completo:

```py
saldo = input("Please enter Saldo: ")


def isNumber(value):
    try:
        float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


while not isNumber(saldo):
    print("Please enter a valid value: ")
    saldo = input("Please enter Saldo: ")

if isNumber(saldo):
    print("OK")

    saldo = float(saldo)

    if saldo >= 0 and saldo <= 200:
        credito = 0
    if saldo >= 201 and saldo <= 400:
        credito = 0.2 * saldo
    if saldo >= 401 and saldo <= 600:
        credito = 0.3 * saldo
    if saldo > 601:
        credito = 0.4 * saldo
else:
    print("Please Enter a Valid Value: ")
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Consegui resolver a questao.

Comment: @GiovanneLucas O `if isNumber` é desnecessário nesse caso. Se o código saiu do `while` é porque `isNumber` retornou `True`, então não tem porque testar isso de novo. Tem outros detalhes que vc pode acertar também, veja [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444915/112052) :-)